# How to set "hide organizational items if no access to content"?

Tags: cme, authorization, mmc

How do we set "Hide organizational items if no access to content" in the MMC Snap-in?

I couldn't get the setting to work when doing the following:

1. Specific group does not have read to folder “System” (and no parent groups have read).
2. In Tridion MMC Snap-in, set `Hide organizational items if no access to content` from “0” to “1.” Closed the Snap-in and saved changes.
3. Restarted SDL Tridion in IIS and shut down/started SDL Tridion Content Manager in COM+.
4. Refreshed browser as user of the above group (and tried clearing cache).
5. Navigated to the containing folder

**Answer**: Thanks to Senior developer Likhan for explaining I also needed to restart `Tridion Content Manager Service Host`. Details posted below.

Comment: It's common enough to need to restart several Tridion sub-systems at once for this kind of thing. I usually automate it. Some examples of how to do this are to be found at https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ProgrammaticallyRestartTridionContentManager

Comment: Good example, I linked to it from the ["VM" setup page](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/DeveloperVirtualMachine) which also on the Tridion Practice wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Content Manager Explorer, starting with SDL Tridion 2013,  uses the Core Service for all of its functionality, including authorization.

Restarting `Tridion Content Manager Service Host` on the CMS made the setting work so that the next client browser refresh showed a limited set of folders.

Comment: As of 2011 I've always made it a good practice to whenever I restarted the COM+ application, also to restart the Service Host. Depending on what you are doing, you might also want to restart the Publisher. After restarting those tree you will have successfully cleared the system in most cases.

Comment: Good idea, I added the [script Dominic mentions](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ProgrammaticallyRestartTridionContentManager) to make sure I get all of them. Maybe overkill in a production environment, but works for development.